# angular + spring mvc 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: json, angularjs, spring

Добрый вечер. Пытаюсь отправить объект юзера с фронтенда на спринг контроллер. Почему-то вылетает ошибка 400 (Bad Request). 
Мой сервис:

```
service.createUser = function (user) {
    console.log("Service. Creating user ",user);
    return http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/user/createUser',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {user: user}
    })
};
```

юзер на фронтенде (заполненный данными. 1-2 роли):

```
$scope.user = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    roles: []
};
```

Спринг контроллер:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/createUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public boolean createUser(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {
    System.out.println(userDTO);
    return true;
}}
```

UserDTO

```
public class UserDTO {

private Long id;
private String email;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String password;
private List<Role> roles;

//getters and setters
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить. Спасибо.

UPD:

Исправил ситуацию добавлением в конфигурацию спринг секьюрити .csrf().disable(). Теперь появилась другая ошибка. Обьект почему-то приходит пустой (поля не иницыализированы), хотя перед отправкой в консоли он заполнен.

[image: Перед отправкой на бекэнд объект заполнен]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPDT 2:
Проблема была в том, чтоб в userdto поле ролей был интерфейс Role а не его реализация RoleImpl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, Angular не умеет отправлять GET-запрос с телом сообщения (message body). Более того стандарт HTTP хоть и не запрещает передавать данные в теле GET-запросов не предусматривает, чтобы сервер как-то их обрабатывал.

В вашем случае нужно:

- либо передавать данные в query-параметрах:

  ```
  $http({
    url: user.details_path, 
    method: "GET",
    params: { id: user.id, ... }  
  });
  ```

  но в этом случае в методе контроллера в Spring нужно будет использовать `@RequestParam` для кадого поля вместо `@RequestBody`.
- либо, что правильнее, использовать `POST` для создания объектов и `PUT` для изменения.

  Объект в этом случае у вас приходит пустым, потому что в запросе у вас объект User лежит внутри поля user.  Попробуйте заменить

  ```
  data: {user: user}
  ```

  на

  ```
  data: user
  ```

Comment: Сделал всё, как вы написали (поменял на метод post, и изменил data: {user: user} на data: user). Теперь  вываливается 400 Bad Request.

Comment: Хорошо бы логов с сервера. Гадать сложно.

Comment: description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Проверьте в Developer Tools в браузере: отправляется валидный JSON?

Comment: добавил картинку в первый пост. Перед отправкой объект заполнен нормально

Comment: Я имел в виду фактический Request на вкладке Network.

Comment: добавил фактический Request

Comment: Может быть дело в том, что вы присылаете в поле `roles` список строк, а ожидаете список объектов `Role`?

Comment: Да, скорее всего в этом проблема. Закоментировал роли у обьекта, и всё отправляется. Тогда вопрос в другом, как правильно отправлять объект в объекте (тоесть обьект роли как поле юзера). Сейчас он имеет вид: roles=[{title:ROLE_ADMIN}, {ROLE_USER}]. Как его нужно поменять?

Comment: Все, я всё понял. Проблема была в том, чтоб в userdto поле ролей был интерфейс Role а не его реализация RoleImpl. Все заработало. Спасибо вам за потраченное время.

Answer (score 0):

Пока не могу оставлять комментарии, у Вас в запросе url: '/user/createUser', а в spring controller value = "/createUser", так и должно быть?
Еще предполагается использовать для сохранения(update) объекта метод PUT

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/user", method = PUT)
public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@RequestBody User user){
    userService.saveUser(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: По поводу url у меня весь класс помечен как @RestController и @RequestMapping("/user"). По поводу методов передачи данных, у меня почему-то работает только get. Если например поменять на пост - выскакивает 403 (Forbidden)..